# Where to download Chrome 32bit?

Tags: debian, chrome, 32bit

Google has [discontinued the 32bit Version of Chrome](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/FoE6sL-p6oU) so on a 32bit Debian machine it's not possible anymore to update the APT repository:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Also has the .deb file removed from Google servers as it seems.

**Is there any alternative `.deb` download of the last release (46?) available somewhere?**

Reason: For an automated Debian build system (`debootstrap`-based) I urgently need a way to install Google Chrome 32bit v46 (or similar). Switching to another browser (including Chromium) is not a quick enough option for me at the moment..

Comment: The last one I'm aware of was `google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb`

Comment: While it's not a full answer - if you google for the above filename, you'll find it on plenty of mirrors where it's not been deleted yet.  This is a time sensitive question however, so a bit unusual for StackExchange.

Comment: The exact filename you provided was indeed all I needed. Thanks

Comment: How can I verify the authenticity of the package. Any way to find a Release file?

Comment: can you just install chromium and create a chrome link that points to it?

Answer (score 8):

Download google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb here
http://bbgentoo.ilb.ru/distfiles/

Comment: ArchLinux also references the latest official Google Chrome 32bits version with checksums at: https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=chromium-widevine.

Answer (score 7):

So your question is kind of time sensitive (unless someone starts offering unofficial 32bit builds of Chrome, if that's even possible).  I'll try and provide a slightly more generic answer  to the question, "the package I want is no longer available, what can I do?"

One solution, is that if you have a machine which recently downloaded the `.deb`, it may still be present in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

For example,

```
trinity:/usr# ls -l /var/cache/apt/archives/google*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47451856 Feb  3 22:00 /var/cache/apt/archives/google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.103-1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47625502 Feb  9 18:40 /var/cache/apt/archives/google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.109-1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47539368 Feb 18 20:22 /var/cache/apt/archives/google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47583326 Jan 20 22:41 /var/cache/apt/archives/google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.82-1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47294044 Jan 27 20:58 /var/cache/apt/archives/google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.97-1_i386.deb
```

If you want to use it on a small number of machines, you could just copy the `.deb` file and install it manually using dkpg.

However, if you want to install it on many machines, or use it for builds, then one option is to build your own [local Debian repository for it](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use Chrome application.
When you have a debian mirror such as:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian sid main contrib non-free
```

You can install Chrome as `chromium`, Chrome forked from chromium project.
You can do :

```
apt-get install chromium
```

Comment: Right, but they aren't exactly the same application

Comment: It's better because doesn't has backdoor

Comment: @PersianGulf True, but it also lacks proprietary things like Flash, etc. But maybe those can be installed easily?

Comment: chromium doesn't include widevine.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install the alternative of the Google Chrome for the 32 bit: [Chromium Web Browser](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium) !