# Where to download chrome remote desktop 32 bit for ubuntu 12.04 as it is discontinued by google?

Tags: debian, chrome, 32bit

I installed the the 32 bit version of google chrome in ubuntu 12.04 using the post 
[Where to download Chrome 32bit since it has been discontinued by Google?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267587/where-to-download-chrome-32bit-since-it-has-been-discontinued-by-google)

My objective is to install the 32 bit version of the debian package of chrome remote desktop host component. When i click on the 32 bit debian package inside the link provided below by google i get an error. Please help....
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en